# Why aren't my values passed to the properties of my class?

Tags: c#, oop, class

So I have a class:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }

    public Person()
    {
        AddPerson();
    }

    private void AddPerson()
    {
        string fn = this.Firstname;
        string ln = this.Lastname;
        // Do something with these values
        // Probably involves adding to a database
    }

}
```

And I have some code that will instantiate an object and add it to the database, returning the the object of type `Person`:

```
Person me = new Person()
{
    Firstname = "Piers",
    Lastname = "Karsenbarg"
};
```

However, when I debug this, and get to the `AddPerson()` method, the properties `this.Firstname` and `this.Lastname` don't have anything in them (in this case are empty).

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: _"Where am I going wrong?"_ - you're making your constructor do  more work than bringing the object in a usable state. If `AddPerson` adds a person to a database, it is discutable that that is a `Person` method, but if it is required at that point, it should be public and named appropriately (`AddPersonToDatabase`) and should never be called automatically, let alone from the constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because properties are assigned after constructor is called. Basicaly, this:

```
Person me = new Person()
{
    Firstname = "Piers",
    Lastname = "Karsenbarg"
};
```

is the *same* as:

```
Person me = new Person();
me.Firstname = "Piers";
me.Lastname = "Karsenbarg";
```

Only difference here is syntax. In your case you may want to pass those variables via parametrized constructor (`new Person("Piers", "Karsenbarg")`).

Comment: How would you recommend doing this then? Maybe just have another method that does the adding after? So instantiate the new object and then call `me.Save()` that would run the save method (which would probably do the same as the `AddPerson()` method, just be public instead?

Comment: Just seen your update. I do have a parameterized constructor, but I was wondering the best way of doing it.

Comment: There are couple ways, it depends on what you need. I've recommended parametrized constructor for this (based on what I see in your question).

Answer (score 1):

You have not assigned any values to your properties.  I would suggest passing in the names you want in the constructor:

```
   public class Person
{
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }

    public Person(string firstname, lastname)
    {
        this.Firstname = firstname;
        this.Lastname = lastname;
        AddPerson();
    }

    private void AddPerson()
    {
        string fn = this.Firstname;
        string ln = this.Lastname;
        // Do something with these values
        // Probably involves adding to a database
    }

}
```

A person cannot exist without a firstname or lastname so this makes logical sense

Comment: _"A person cannot exist without a firstname or lastname"_ - it might be nitpicking given the application constraints, but: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).